# SQL Server : rollup missing a summarization

Tags: sql-server

I have two table containing info, one for vms, one for hosts. When using rollup, the vcpu info from the virtual table is fine, but I can't seem to get the host cpu numbers to summarize. Thoughts?

```
select 
    cluster, v.esxhostname, 
    sum(v.numcpu) as totvcpu,
    (sum((h.CpuSockets * h.CpuCoresPerSocket))/(count(esxhostname))) as pcores, 
    (sum(v.numcpu) / (sum((h.CpuSockets * h.CpuCoresPerSocket)) / (count(esxhostname)))) as ratio
from 
    vmstats as v
inner join 
    hoststats as h on v.esxhostname = h.name
where 
    v.date = '7-24-20' and h.date = '7-24-20'
group by  
    rollup (cluster, v.EsxHostName)
order by 
    cluster, esxhostname asc
```

and it produces this.... the row with NULL NULL is the total of all, except the pcores column. The next row is a cluster summry, with vcpu correct, but pcores showing 32 rather than 384, and this is the issue.

```
cluster     esxhostname  totvcpu pcores ratio
NULL        NULL            2793 31.7   88.0635403329065
usaus01pc1  NULL            352 32  11
usaus01pc1  10.102.131.20   26  32  0.8125
usaus01pc1  10.102.131.22   22  32  0.6875
usaus01pc1  10.102.131.24   24  32  0.75
usaus01pc1  10.102.131.26   20  32  0.625
usaus01pc1  10.102.131.28   49  32  1.53125
usaus01pc1  10.102.131.30   25  32  0.78125
usaus01pc1  10.102.131.32   42  32  1.3125
usaus01pc1  10.102.131.34   40  32  1.25
usaus01pc1  10.102.131.36   28  32  0.875
usaus01pc1  10.102.131.38   26  32  0.8125
usaus01pc1  10.102.131.40   18  32  0.5625
usaus01pc1  10.102.131.42   32  32  1
usaus01pc2  NULL            86  24  3.58333333333333
usaus01pc2  10.102.131.120  12  24  0.5
snip
```

Comment: Formatting your sample data does wonders for making them readable. What are you expected results as well?

Comment: I couldn't get it to line up between the editor and posting. On the first row of data, the 2793 is wrong - it's too high, which is supposed to be a total of the individual rows. The 31.7 number however, isn't summing. The 2nd row, with one NULL, shows 352 which is correct and is the total summary (grouped by usaus01pc1), however, it reports 32, where it should be 384 (32 12 times.)

Comment: What do you mean with `snip` at the end of your results? Is this only a snippet of the full output? Because if the 352 number is correct, then the 86 number in the same column should be correct as well (same aggregation level), but that does not match with the rows below it. If the results are incomplete, then the 2793 number on top can still make sense...

Comment: Yes, the full output is long. I'm focused on the next column, with all the 32's.